# Pending test in Ert

Tags: ert, testing

I'm currently starting to build a package the TDD way, and for that I'm using `ert`, following `ert-runner` *opinions*.

I would like to write a set of **pending tests**, to identify what I have I to test, before to implement the test.

*Is it possible to write pending test in `ert`?*

If so how? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a call to `ert-skip` at the beginning of your test would be the solution I believe. If you'd like, you can pass the string "pending" to the function to better show why it was skipped.

```
(ert-deftest my-pending-test ()
  (ert-skip "pending")
  (should (dostuff)))
```

Comment: Hey @Jordon, this is working indeed, however when I run it with `ert-runner` the test is identified as Passing. (*which is finally the same compared with no body, as I way doing until now*).
Do you know if there is a way the test is identified as neither failed neither passing? :)

Comment: maybe it's a bug in `ert-runner`?

Answer (score 4):

It's not specifically for "pending", but marking the test as expected to fail seems like it would be what you want: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ert/Expected-Failures.html

> add `:expected-result :failed' to the test definition:
>
> ```
>  (ert-deftest future-bug ()
>    "Test `time-forward' with negative arguments.
>  Since this functionality isn't implemented, the test is known to fail."
>    :expected-result :failed
>    (time-forward -1))
> ```
>
> ERT will still display a small `f' in the progress bar as a
>   reminder that there is a known bug, and will count the test as failed,
>   but it will be quiet about it otherwise.